# Como iterar array php

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte bloco que alimenta um array

```
$insert = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
   $insert[] = array(
                 "os"       => $cdOs,
                 "name"     => $iten->name
                 );
}
```

O array retorna assim:

> ```
> array (size=1)  0 =>     array (size=3)      'os' => string '84822' (length=5)      'name' => string 'Desert.jpg' (length=10)
> ```

Estou tentando recuperar os dados assim:

```
foreach ( $values as $valor => $chave) {
  echo "Codigo da os insert: ".$chave->os." \n";   
}
```

Mas não mostra nada

Comment: É um array não um objeto, logo precisa de colchetes `['chave']` para acesar e não `->`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem que utilizar parênteses rectos. Quando acede a uma posição de um array utiliza "[]", quando acede a um objeto utiliza "->".

```
foreach ( $values as $valor => $chave) {
  echo "Codigo da os insert: " . $chave['os'] . " \n";   
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!